# My Access database does not returns any row with a xsd DataSet

Tags: .net, ms-access, xsd, dataset

I have to import an Access database. When I copy/pasted the mdb file into the application, it created a corresponding XSD dataset, so I went along with it (I figured it would be much easier than to query it using ODBC).
I try to query the database using these lines :

```
        var dsAccess = new data.DATAGESTIONDataSet();
        var RaisonSociales = from rs in dsAccess.Tb_Raison_Soc
                             select rs;
        foreach (var rs in RaisonSociales)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(rs.Raison_Soc);
        }
```

Unfortunately, the select statement does not return any row.

The "Linq to SQL class" and ADO.Net Entity Framework do not support MS Access :(

Any idea ?
Thanks

**EDIT** : here is the solution, thanks to @Daniel Hilgart :

```
        var cn = new OleDbConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ImportSerce.Properties.Settings.DATAGESTIONConnectionString"].ToString());
        var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Tb_Raison_Soc]", cn);
        var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        var tds = new data.DATAGESTIONDataSet();
        da.Fill(tds, tds.Tb_Raison_Soc.TableName);
        var rsMS = from rs in tds.Tb_Raison_Soc
                   select rs;
        foreach (var rs in rsMS)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(rs.Raison_Soc);
        }
```

Not exactly as pretty, and a bit cumbersome to work with, but at least it works. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fill the `DataSet` by calling `Fill` on the generated DataAdapter passing your `DataSet` and the table name. More info can be found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320714